# - not sure how to combine, right now I am getting comma in between them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, string

- I am new to js.
- I am trying to write a code which replaces space with 0.
- I got partial output but how to get to like this "call0cell0".
- not sure how to combine, right now I am getting comma in between them
- providing code below

```or-tag-here
var word = "cell  call  ";
var replaceWord = [];

for (i=0; i < word.length; i++) {
    replaceWord.push(word[i]);

    if (word[i] === " ") {
        replaceWord.pop(word[i] = ' ');
        replaceWord.push(word[i] = '0');
    }
}

console.log("result----->" + replaceWord);
```

Comment: Use `str.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').replace(' ', '0');`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>



<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str ="cell  call  ";
    var res = str.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').replace(' ', '0');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: can you tell me how to use without regular expressions

Comment: For you required result, `str.replace(/\s\s+/g, '0');`

Comment: @texirv: With Regular expression it makes things easy, why you don't wanna use Regex. Also, without Regex, then you don't know how many spaces are there between non-space characters. If you know that maximum say 2,3 spaces can be there then you can do `.replace(' ', '0')` that many number of times.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: Yes, I just did 2 times replace because OP should understand the working :), else what you mentioned is better.

Comment: @OmSao since requirement is I should not use regular expression

Comment: @texirv: Then you must be knowing beforehand that maxiumum how many spaces can be there. In that case suppose maximum 3 spaces can be there(it can be 1, 2 or 3 spaces). So, use replace 3 times.
`str.replace(' ', '0').replace(' ', '').replace(' ', '');`

Here, you are replaceing all spaces to 0 and then all spaces to nothing.
I hope you got it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something more simple like

```
var word = "cell  call  ";
var replaceWord = word.replace(/ /g,"0");
console.log("result----->" + replaceWord);
```

if you don't want to use regular expresion you can do it like this

```
var word = "cell  call  ";
replaceWord = word.split(' ').join('0')
console.log("result----->" + replaceWord);
```

Comment: There could be repeated spaces.

Comment: @xploshioOn can you tell me how to use without regular expressions

Comment: I edited the answer with an option to solve this without regular expressions, but why you don't want to use regular expressions?

Comment: @xploshioOn since requirement is I should not use regular expression

Comment: Ok, so the second option is your friend ;)

Comment: @xploshioOn hello can you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600110/minimise-the-code-since-i-am-using-the-same-code-only-the-content-in-p-tags-chan

Answer (score 0):

In Addition to the other answers that use RegEx (which you shouldn't how you stated), you could use your own solution if it is correct - you said your only problem were the

> comma in between them

so if your problem only is to Combine the elements of the Array to a string, you only have to Change the last line of your own code from `console.log("result----->" + replaceWord);` to `console.log("result----->" + replaceWord.join(''));`

With the `join()` method, you get a string of all the elements of the Array, joined by the string you give `join()` as an Argument. per Default, so if you leave the brackets empty and pass no Argument, `join()` joins the elements with a comma, which is what's Happening in your code right now.

So if you use `join('')` instead, you join every element with `''`, which is an empty string, and so nothing is in between the characters anymore